# Sending live output from Exchange powershell to textbox in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have an Exchange Powershell script that will move email from one account to another. when you invoke the code thru Powershell it provides you with real time data stats. how can I capture that and feed it into a text box that will provide that "live feed". Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
    public void RunPowerShell()
    {            
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
        Runspace runSpace;

        //create the runspace
        runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);

        //insert try here
        runSpace.Open();

        //for exchange 2010 use "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010"
        rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);

        //set up the pipeline to run the powershell command 
        Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

        //create the scripts to use
        String sScript = "Add-MailboxPermission -Identity " + FromEmailAccount.Text + " -User Administrator -AccessRights FullAccess";
        String sScript1 = "Add-MailboxPermission -Identity " + ToEmailAccount.Text + " -User Administrator -AccessRights FullAccess";
        String sScript2 = "Export-Mailbox -Identity " + FromEmailAccount.Text + " -TargetMailbox " + ToEmailAccount.Text + " -TargetFolder " + FromEmailAccount.Text + " -Confirm:$false";

        //invoke the scripts
        pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(sScript);
        pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(sScript1);
        pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(sScript2);

        Collection<PSObject> commandResults = pipeLine.Invoke();

        //loop through the results of the command and load the ?
        foreach (PSObject results in commandResults)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = results.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(results.Properties["DisplayName"].Value.ToString(),@"Name");
        }

        //close the pipelin and runspace
        pipeLine.Dispose();
        runSpace.Close();

        //create completed message
        MessageBox.Show(@"Email migration is complete", @"Done");
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(sScript2);
```

Try adding

```
pipeLine.Commands.Add("out-string");
```

I think that will take all the output (PSObjects) and convert them to a string. That might be easier for you to parse and display in the TextBox.

Here's an example of how to update the GUI. In the `scriptText` variable I define two PowerShell functions. You'll want to change the first function to have the code to start the mailbox export. Then you'll want to change the second function to query the export and find out what percent done it is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PowerShellLiveUpdateExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Setup the BackgroundWorker
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textbox1.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %");
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            string scriptText = @"
                function startExport() {
                    $script:finishtime = (get-date).addminutes(1)
                }

                function getPercentDone() {
                    $timeleft = new-timespan $(get-date) $finishtime
                    return [math]::truncate(100 - ($timeleft.totalseconds / 60) * 100)
                }

                startExport";

            PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
            psExec.AddScript(scriptText);

            // Start the export
            psExec.Invoke();

            // Flush the currently added commands
            psExec.Commands.Clear();

            Collection<PSObject> results;
            Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
            int percent = 0;

            // Report on the export
            while (percent < 100)
            {
                // Update every second
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                psExec.AddScript("getPercentDone | out-string");
                results = psExec.Invoke();
                errors = psExec.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    Int32.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out percent);
                    worker.ReportProgress(percent);
                }
            }
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                textbox1.Text = "Canceled!";
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                textbox1.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                textbox1.Text = "Done!";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I think you'd want to change the PowerShell code to look something like:

```
function startExport() {
    $script:exportid = new-mailboxexportrequest -mailbox "John Doe" -filepath  '\\fileshare\john.doe.pst' -baditemlimit $baditemlimit
    # Give the export some time to get settled
    start-sleep 10
}

function getPercentDone() {
    $export = get-mailboxexportrequest $script:exportid
    $exportstats = $export | get-mailboxexportrequeststatistics
    return $exportstats.PercentComplete
}
```

But I haven't tested that.

Comment: I did that, then set my 
    richtextbox.text = results.toString() 
and did get the final output. Thats half way there. Im looking for the what i call live feed, where it updates the amount of data that has been transferred, the rate, what folders its currently moving, etc. Thanks for the help Elijah.

Comment: To get live feed it's going to be a bit more difficult. You're going to have to execute PowerShell on a separate thread from the thread your GUI runs on. The PowerShell thread will need to run a loop that continually gets the status every few seconds by running get-mailboxexportrequest | get-mailboxexportrequeststatistics, parses the output and then updates the GUI in a thread safe manor.

Comment: that sounds Exactly like what im looking for. Thanks for the tip on that one, its much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer demo how to solve the full question. Please let me know if you have any trouble using it.

Comment: I will look at this more later this week and play with it. Thanks a bunch for the info. cant wait to geek out on this!